# Запрос из нескольких связанных таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть 2 связанные таблицы в базе данных. Необходимо создать запрос, который будет выбирать поля `name` записей из первой таблицы, в которых поле `type` во второй равно определенному значению.

То есть, таблицы выглядят, например, так:

```
id    name
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3

id    type
2     1
3     4
```

Создаем запрос:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE type = 4
```

Выберется запись `name3`. Как можно модифицировать запрос, чтобы условие `WHERE` он проверял именно во второй таблице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого Вам нужно [объединить](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) эти две таблицы, а 
после этого уже сделать выборку колонок из первой таблицы применив фильтр к колонкам второй таблицы:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.type = 4
```

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28b22/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id and t2.type = 4
```